# how to access on sql in background mode

Tags: flutter

I'm using Sqflite with background headless mode when I terminated app and I executed job when app is open it's work great but when I terminated app it's give me this issue only on android

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)

i'm work on flutter < 1.2
this is MainActivity.kt file

```
package xxx.xxx.xxx

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

import android.os.Build
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver
import android.view.WindowManager
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is supported for flutter < 1.12. You might need to upgrade your project and follow the steps described here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects (don't forget the meta-data too)